# Reapply UK visit visa, can I change some data?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

In the application question about " how much you earn each month after tax? In the 1st application we declared Php 10400. That is from Php 400 (daily rate) x 26 working days, and we explained that my sister is  exempted from tax since she earns minimum wage. But we forget to include the 1500 allowance she receives every month, because it was not stated in her payslips.

Now, we plan to correct this in the second application from Php 10400, we will declare Php11,900, that amount is from 10400+1,500 allowance the company gives, since in the salary received certificate allowance is included.

The main ground for the refusal was the proof of salary received since she doesnt have bank statement since they receives cash payment, and now we are providing salary received certificate from the company.

My question, would it be fine to change the declared income after tax each month? And would it not be another ground for refusal?

Thanks a lot.
Waiting for advice.

Comment: It should be fine to explain the reason for the difference. But UKVI will still expect bank statements to be provided https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: We are also providing 3mos bank statement from her savings account which she forget to submit since it was just her personal saving she started in december 2018

Comment: Six months’ statements would be more typical. If the refusal is very recent, and there is no urgent need to travel, I would consider waiting until your sister can provide a longer set of statements.

Comment: Thanks again Traveller. My sister can provide her personal savings bank statement for 6 months, unfortunately the  May 2018- November 2018 don't have any transaction or flow. It only has Php 500 as maintaining balance. Her last transaction there was in 2017 to February 2018. She restarted saving in Dec 2018, that is why we plan to submt bank statement from Dec 2018 to present date. Target travel date is in April